# Does the pop_back() of std::list de-allocate memory?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've created a list of stacks.

```
using namespace std;
list<stack<int>*> stacks;
stack<int> *st = new stack<int>();      //LINE0
stacks.push_back(st);
st->push(10);   
stack<int> *last = stacks.back();
stacks.pop_back();    //LINE1
delete last;          //LINE2
```

Does LINE1 de-allocate memory allocated at LINE0 automatically? Do I need LINE2?

Comment: Why are you using owning raw pointers?  Use values.  Or at _least_ use `std::unique_ptr`...

Comment: If the template class delete the pointer, how can it accept another case that is push in a pointer to a static variable(not dynamic)?

Answer (score 5):

You allocated memory for the stack using `new`, so yes, you'll need to `delete` it manually. To make life easier, use a `list<stack<int>>` instead, it's unlikely you need a list of pointers.

```
list<stack<int>> stacks;
stack<int> st = stack<int>();
stacks.push_back(st);
stacks.back().push(10);   
stack<int> last = stacks.back();
stacks.pop_back();
```

No need to bother with managing memory anymore. If you really need a list of pointers, use a smart pointer instead of raw pointers.

```
list<unique_ptr<stack<int>>> stacks;
auto st = unique_ptr(new stack<int>());
stacks.push_back(std::move(st));
stacks.back()->push(10);   
auto last = std::move(stacks.back());
stacks.pop_back();
```

Again, you don't need to worry about manually freeing memory. With C++14, you can also get rid of the `new`.

```
auto st = make_unique<int>();
```

Comment: Is it alright to put a `unique_ptr` in a `std::list`? Does `std::list` guarantee no copying?

Comment: @Cramer `unique_ptr` is moveable, and the `list` will move the elements as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you do need your `LINE2`,

```cpp
stacks.pop_back();
```

only de-allocates the memory needed for the `stack<int>*` it holds, not the memory of the actually `stack<int>` that's being pointed to.

It actually can't really know that since you could also `push_back` a pointer to a `stack<int>` with automatic storage into it like:

```cpp
list<stack<int>*> stacks;
stack<int> st;
stacks.push_back(&st);
stacks.pop_back() // how would it know that it's safe to call delete?
```

Trying to de-allocate in this case would wreak havoc and probably cause a segmentation fault or the like.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't - you do need LINE2. The list is guaranteed to call the **destructor** of its elements - but it does NOT call `delete`, and pointers don't have destructors. If you insert a dynamically-allocated pointer into the list, you're still responsible for cleaning it up.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is, if you have a `new`, there needs to be a `delete` somewhere, the only exception to this are smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`. So here, you do need LINE2.

Comment: If you have `make_unique` then you don't need any `new` or `delete`, except for placement-new.